# Use one property of a Typescript interface in an other interface

Tags: typescript, interface

Suppose I have a Typescript Interface as follows

```
export interface IMyObj {
    id: string;
    type: 'AA' | 'AZ' | 'XY';
    ...
}
```

Now I need an other interface which also has that `type` field

```
export interface IMyOtherObj {
    ...
    type: 'AA' | 'AZ' | 'XY';
    ...
}
```

As you can see I have duplicated the values of `type`. So my question is, how can I reuse `IMyObj.type` in my `IMyOtherObj` interface? I tried this

```
export interface IMyOtherObj {
    ...
    type: IMyObj.type; // -> error
    ...
}
```

I think I'm close but so far no luck, any suggestions?

Comment: is it not possible to just extract those as a type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your issue is that TS type system has no `.` property access but [indexed property type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types), change one thing in your type definition:

```
type: IMyObj['type']
```

Comment: What if I need something like X and the interface has a property which is X[]? Is extracting  the type of X still possible? As this method would then return X[].

Answer (score 2):

Define an [enumeration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) for your property `type`, such as

```
enum MyEnum {
    Aa = "AA",
    Az = "AZ",
    Xy = "XY"
}
```

and use it like this;

```
export interface IMyObj {
    id: string;
    type: MyEnum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new interface that contains only the type property definition, then extend from that in your others:

```
export interface ITypedObj {
    type: 'AA' | 'AZ' | 'XY';
}

export interface IMyObj extends ITypedObj {
    id: string;
}
```

[TS Handbook: Extending Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the extends functionality

so you would have

```js
export interface IMyObj {
    id: string;
    type: 'AA' | 'AZ' | 'XY';
    ...
}
```

and then

```js
export interface IMyOtherObj extends IMyObj{
    ...
    otherthings: string;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

1 extract the type of the field type as it's own type and use it in both places.

```js
type ObjectType = 'AA' | 'AZ' | 'XY'
interface A {
  type: ObjectType;

}
interface B {
  type: ObjectType
}
```

Or if you can not modify the first interface, you can make the second interface extend a subtype of the first one.

```js
interface A {
  type: 'AA' | 'AZ' | 'XY';

}

interface B extends Pick<A, 'type'> {

}
```